# On nilpotent factor group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with the property that $G/N$ is nilpotent. Prove that there exists a nilpotent subgroup $H$ of $G$ satisfying $G = HN$.

This is problem 223 on page 24 of http://www.math.kent.edu/~white/qual/list/all.pdf. I think that Frattini's argument may be useful.

Comment: In what connection have you encountered this exercise? Ie, what sort of results are you expected to use in solving it?

Comment: I think and try to use Frattini's argument. Maybe it's useful.

Comment: http://www.math.kent.edu/~white/qual/list/all.pdf
problem 223 page 24

Comment: @chuyenvien94 I have edited these comments into the question for you - next time you should include this kind of context in the statement of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use induction on $|G|$. If all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are normal, then $G$ is nilpotent. Otherwise, there exists a non-normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$. Apply the Frattini argument to $PN \unlhd G$ to get $G=NN_G(P)$ and then apply induction to $N_G(P)$.

Comment: Why is $PN$ normal in $G$?

Comment: Frattini's argument http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini's_argument

Comment: But why can choose $H=N_{G}(P)$? Is $N_{G}(P)$ nilpotent ? Can you explain more precisely to me ?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of the nilpotent group $G/N$, so $PN/N$ is normal in $G/N$ and hence $PN$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 $N_G(P)$ is not necessarily nilpotent. The point is that its order is less than $G$, so we can assume by induction that it has a nilpotent subgroup $H$ with $HN_N(P) = N_G(P)$, but then $HN=G$, so we are done.

Comment: Why $HN_{N}\left(P\right)=N_{G}\left(P\right)\Rightarrow HN=G$

Comment: That follows from what I've written already!

Comment: Thank you very much, Derek Holt

Comment: I don't understand why we can assume by induction that $N_{G}\left(P\right)$ has a nilpotent subgroup $H$ with $HN_{N}\left(P\right)=N_{G}\left(P\right)$, I think that equality doesn't satisfy Frattini's argument. Can you explain more precisely to me? Thank you

Comment: $|N_G(P)| < |G|$, so we can assume by induction that the result we are trying to prove is true for $N_G(P)$. Since $N_G(P)/N_N(P) \cong G/N$, which is nilpotent, we have a subgroup $H$ with $HN_N(P)=N_G(P)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Derek Holt. I 've understood already.