# On nilpotent factor group (cont.)

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ abelian, $N\triangleleft G$ with the property that $G/N$ is nilpotent. Assume that $Z\left(G\right)=\left\{ e\right\} $ , $\exists K\leq G$, $K$ is nilpotent and $G=NK$. Prove that $K\cap N=\left\{ e\right\}$ and  $K=N_{G}\left(K\right)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts. You should probably also add what problem this is and where from, as it seems likely to be from the same place as your last question.

Comment: I moved it here to see it esier.

Comment: That does not mean you should not include all the relevant information in the question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525659/on-nilpotent-group
In that question, we are done about the existence of such $K$

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question itself, like you were asked to on the previous question.

Comment: That's all. I don't have any other opinions about the relevant information to the question. I'm trying to prove it.

Comment: OK, here is a hint. Show that, if $K \cap N \ne \{ e \}$, then $K \cap Z(G) \ne \{ e \}$.

Comment: The information provided in these comments are relevant to the question. Those are the ones I meant you should add to the question itself.

Comment: Since $N$
  is abelian, we have $Z\left(N\right)=N$
 . So if $K\cap N\neq\left\{ e\right\} \Leftrightarrow K\cap Z\left(N\right)\neq\left\{ e\right\}$ 
 . Since $K\cap Z\left(N\right)\subseteq K\cap Z\left(G\right)$
 , we have $K\cap Z\left(G\right)\neq\left\{ e\right\} \Rightarrow Z\left(G\right)\neq\left\{ e\right\}$ 
  a contradiction. Thus $K\cap N=\left\{ e\right\}$

Comment: Can anyone tell me a hint to prove $K=N_{G}\left(K\right)$

Comment: Help me, please

Comment: $K\cap N\neq\lbrace e\rbrace\implies Z(K)\cap N\neq\lbrace e\rbrace$, yet $Z(K)\cap N\subset Z(G)$. Now if $n\in N_G(K)$, consider $[n,k]$ for some $k\in K$...

Comment: Prove that $N_N(K) \le Z(G)$.

Comment: I think $N$
  is abelian, hence $N$
  is nilpotent, $G=NK$
  so $G$
  is nilpotent and $K\lneqq N_{G}\left(K\right)$

Comment: Nonsense. How could $G$ be nil potent and have trivial center?!

Comment: But $G=NK$, $N$ nilpotent and $K$ nilpotent???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $N$ is abelian, $Z(N)=N$. So $K\cap N\neq\left\{ e\right\} \Leftrightarrow K\cap Z\left(N\right)\neq\left\{ e\right\}$. Since $K\cap Z\left(N\right)\subseteq K\cap Z\left(G\right)$, $K\cap Z\left(G\right)\neq\left\{ e\right\} \Rightarrow Z\left(G\right)\neq\left\{ e\right\}$ a contradiction.
$G/K\cong NK/K\cong N/\left(K\cap N\right)\cong N$ (since $K\cap N=1$). Since $N$ is abelian, we have $G/K$ is abelian. So $\forall x\in G,xK=Kx$. So $xK=Kx
  \forall x\in K$. That means $N_{G}\left(K\right)\subseteq K$. In addition, $K\trianglelefteq N_{G}\left(K\right)$. Hence $K=N_{G}\left(K\right)
 .$

Comment: Thank you so much, Derek Holt for very nice hints.