# Suppose that both $N$ and $G/N$ are nilpotent. Let $K$ be a nilpotent subgroup of maximal order, such that $G=NK$. Prove that $N_{G}(K)=K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose that both $N$ and $G/N$ are nilpotent. Let $K$ be a nilpotent subgroup of maximal order, such that $G=NK$. Prove that $N_{G}(K)=K$.

I think this fact can be useful: Let $M$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$. If both $M$ and $N$ are nilpotent, so is $MN$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The assumptions look like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526966/on-nilpotent-factor-group-cont/565527#565527

Comment: I asked you what you have done... I do not see your point.... please explain..

Comment: @Nicky Hekster: Does "nilpotent subgroup of maximal order" equivalent to "nilpotent maximal group"?

Comment: OK right - do you mean maximal wrt nilpotency or wrt order? Nilpotent maximal = wrt order, and the subgroup in question happens to be nilpotent. Maximal nilpotent is different.

Comment: "Nilpotent maximal subgroup" is very ambiguous, and you should say exactly what it means. I would normally interpret it as meaning a maximal subgroup that happens to be nilpotent, but it cannot mean that here.

Comment: @Derek Holt - OK, for me nilpotent maximal means it is maximal in order sense, and also nilpotent. I apologize for editting and will re-edit right away!

Comment: I think it is up to  chuyenvien94 to tell us what it means!

Comment: @Derek Holt - absolutely! I edited it back to the orginal question. As it stands, it does make a lot of sense. If $G=N_G(K)$ - the other possibility - then $K$ is normal and $G$ is nilpotent after all.

Comment: As given I don't think the claim is true: suppose $\;G\;$ is nilpotent and finite. Then all its subgroups and quotient groups are nilpotent as well, and we then can always express $\;G=HN\;$ , but it can't be that $\;N_G(H)=H\;$ as a finite nilpotent group has the normalizer property: for any proper subgroup $\;H\;,\;\;H\lneqq N_G(H)\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio: $G$ need not be nilpotent

Comment: Exactly my point, @chuyenvien94 : **if** $\;G\;$ is finite nilpotent then we get a contradiction to what you claim!

Comment: I think in this problem $G$ is not nilpotent precisely

Comment: You don't seem to understand, @chuyenvien94: if your claim is right, then it must be right **also** if $\;G\;$ is nilpotent, right? But in this case, as shown, it is *not* right, so either you add some conditions or you check what's going on (or perhaps it's only me being wrong, of course). All this, of course, assuming you meant *proper* subgroup for $\;K\;$ ...

Comment: $HN$ is not a direct product, right?

Comment: @DonAntonio If $G$ is nilpotent then $K$ (or as you called it $H$) must be equal to $G$ (by maximality) and hence we still have $N_G(K)=K$.